JS fetch headers are not included before request (Flask)
I'm using JS to get the screen width of the page, posting it, and then calling it from within my Flask app HTML template to determine functionality of a graph (either interactive Plotly or an image). I am correctly getting the width, but I have errors either "415 Unsupported Media Type Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'" or "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"
If I don't call the data = request.get_json() line in app.py, I get the second error; it seems like the fetch body is not executing properly and it's just getting the whole page. If I call this line, I get the Unsupported Media Type error, the headers don't log, and the print statement regarding the DOM loading doesn't load either.
I'm very new to JS and just want to get the screen width and pass it back to the Flask app. It seems like even though I have document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () that if I call request.get_json() the code executes before the headers are loaded.
Here are my code snippets:
JS
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        console.log('dom loaded')
        const playlistId = '{{ playlist.playlist_id }}';
        const width = window.innerWidth;
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        };
        console.log('Headers being sent:', headers);
        fetch(`/playlist/${playlistId}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({ width: width })
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Raw response:', response);
            return response.json();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    });

playlist.html (jinja)
    {% if viewport >= 768 %}
        {% for graph in graphs %}
        <div class="features-graph">
            {{ graph[0]|safe }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for graph in graphs %}
        <div class="features-graph">
            <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ graph[1] }}">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

app.py
@app.route('/playlist/<string:playlist_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def playlist_details(playlist_id):
    playlist = Playlist.query.filter_by(playlist_id=playlist_id).first_or_404()
    playlist_tracks = Track.query.filter_by(playlist_id=playlist_id).all()
    sorted_playlists = model_playlists(playlist_id)
    graphs = make_graphs(playlist_id)
    data = request.get_json()
    viewport_width = data['width']
    return render_template('playlist.html', playlist=playlist, playlist_tracks=playlist_tracks, model_playlists=sorted_playlists, graphs = graphs, viewport=viewport_width)

I'm also open to another way to do this without JS or without the POST request.

The controller is returning an HTML page playlist.html when the client wants JSON.

yes! how do i fix that? @Barmar

Use return jsonify(data that should be returned) instead of rendering the HTML template.

@nightrainlily Your code leaves a lot of room for speculation. It is not clear whether the data exchange via JSON is required. It may be that you can use URL parameters within a GET request, render the template and send it back, and then use response.text() to receive and embed the rendered HTML code. It may also make sense to receive the image as a blob.
